# Why does an audio DAC possess deemphasis hardware

Tags: audio, dac

The [CS4334](https://www.cirrus.com/en/pubs/proDatasheet/CS4334-5-8-9_F6.pdf) data sheet states that the deemphasis hardware is enabled if external SCLK (used to latch I2S data) is not used and the pin is grounded.

I want to know, what is deemphasis in context of audio and why is it needed in an audio DAC. In other words, why would audio data be preemphasised to begin with and when?

Comment: Do you understand what de-emphasis is in audio context?  It's not clear if the question is about why do de-emphasis at all, or about how it's implemented in this chip.

Comment: Page 14 https://www.cirrus.com/en/pubs/proDatasheet/CS4334-5-8-9_F6.pdf  If the treble has been boosted at the source to reduce hiss (a pre-emphasis)  you may want to reduce it later (a de-emphasis). If the signal is 'flat' to begin with then there is no need. The chip gives you the option, the default is no de-emphasis.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Historic reasons.

Part of the "red book" CD specification allowed CDs to be recorded with a specific preemphasis characteristic. When used with a 44.1kHz sample rate, to decode those specific CDs (a minority of all CDs) you need to apply the inverse (deemphasis) characteristic.

This can be done externally with an R-C network but it's cheaper to do it on chip.

I doubt anyone has bothered with preemphasis/deemphasis in a new digital audio system for about 20 years... which means you can safely ignore it unless you have a very specific need.

Another historic note : When TV stereo sound was digitised to 14 bit and compressed to 10 bit, a more aggressive preemphasis standard (CCITT J-17, boosting high frequencies by 18.75dB) was used (part of the 1980s NICAM-728 standard). In this system, it was required to get acceptable performance at all, as quantisation noise would have been clearly audible after 10 bit compression.

Preemphasis may have been important when CDs were also planned to be 14 bit, but by the time the CD standard settled on 16 bit, it was much less important, and not much used in the end.

Comment: What benefit does adding preemphasis provide to audio that people actually did this?

Comment: Better signal-noise ratio with very cheap passive circuitry. Boost high frequencies before a noisy process, (e.g. A/D, compression + expansion in NICAM, D/A) then reduce high frequencies, and you have also reduced high frequency noise. If the high frequencies were high amplitude in the first place, the boost clips them of course, but (a) they weren't and (b) if they were, limiters guaranteed they weren't. It was a compromise that made sense at the time, and everyone was familiar with it. FM radio, open reel and cassette tape all used the same technique.

Comment: And how does the hardware/software know when to apply it? I mean, with CDs, did it contain metadata that said so, or was it up to the user setting a switch, like with Dolby NR?

Comment: Metadata. If you can find the Philips "Red Book" it should have the details.